# How to load dijit dialog in IE using javascript?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have an application which contains dijit dialog and we are loading that dialog using .show method in all browsers like mozilla ,chrome,safari but when we do same with IE7,it says zoomChart is undefined .
Note : data-dojo-id="zoomChart"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's the Problem, that the widget wasn't ready loaded at this time.
IE handles many things in other ways the Firefox, etc. What other browsers ignore, disturbs the Ie.

**UPDATE1**

Possible Solution:
This one is setup at the beginning of your Html-Page right afterwards the declaration for the Scripts. In the Init-Function you can load all Modules the you later want to use. dojo/ready and dojo/domReady guarants you, that all nessessary Scripts and Nodes are loaded BEFORE it starts.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   require(["dojo/ready"],function(ready){
        ready(function(){
            init();
        });
    });

 function init(){
     require(["dojo/domReady!"],function(){
          zoomChart.show();    
     });
 }
```

By the way - even with this minimum of code you paste in the comments its nearly impossible to say where the error lies. Please, if the Example above wont work fot you, post all of the code is related to the problem.

Here's a link to dojo/domReady which could be helpful for you:

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/domReady.html#dojo-domready

Regards

Comment: thanks MiBrock ,but now its throwing error saying that nodeType is null or not an object

Comment: <div data-dojo-type="dijit/dialog" data-dojo-id="zoomChart" title="Zoom" id="zoom_chart_popup" style="display:none;">
<div class="dijitarea" id="zoom_chart_popup_wrapper">
<div id="chart_zoom_wrapper">
<div id="chart_zoom" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane"></div>
Now in javascript file 
i write 
zoomChart.show();

Comment: Updates my Code - have a look